# MySQL short but highly complex results problem w/ two variations of search

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp

My search is working as expected, but I have an added factor which I cannot sort out.

This is the breakdown of what I need to achieve in one query:

$ApplicantAge **BETWEEN** Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age.
**NOT** 'PlanDetail.company_id' => '27'

$PsSpouseAge **BETWEEN** Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age.
**WHERE** 'PlanDetail.company_id' => '27'

So as you can see with $ApplicantAge matches, I need to get all records that do not have company_id  = 27, and then where $PsSpouseAge matches, only get records with the company_id = 27.

So all records merge together... So essentially there are two queries on the same data at the same time and then all records merged into the result.

As I said, my search is working fine, but I need to integrate this in and sort out the MySQL which I am having 0 luck with.

I've tried many AND / OR AND AND options, and the closest I can get is overwriting the first part of the query with the second part which of course does no good.

What I am trying now:

```
'conditions' => array(
            'AND'  => array(
                array($ApplicantAge . ' BETWEEN Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age'),
                    'AND' => array('Zips.title' => $Zip),
                    'AND' => array('Applicant.amount' => array($comboType, $memberCount)),
                    'NOT' => array('PlanDetail.company_id' => '27'),

                array('OR' =>
                    array($PsSpouseAge . ' BETWEEN Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age'),
                    'AND' => array('Zips.title'       => $Zip),
                    'AND' => array('Applicant.amount' => array($comboType, $memberCount)),
                    'AND' => array('PlanDetail.company_id' => '27'))
                )),
```

And my SQL output is so:

```
WHERE ((19 BETWEEN `Age`.`Min_Age` AND `Age`.`Max_age`) AND (`Applicant`.`amount` IN ('as', '2')) AND (NOT (`PlanDetail`.`company_id` = 27)) AND (((21 BETWEEN `Age`.`Min_Age` AND `Age`.`Max_age`) AND (`PlanDetail`.`company_id` = 27))))
```

Comment: General tips for all SQL type questions:  
1. Include some description of the tables used.
2. State the desired result in plain English.

Comment: Tables are not very relevant in this scenario, because my search is working totally fine, but I just need to get my query (SQL) looking correct with CakePHP naming conventions. That's what I can't solve. I described my object in plain English above.

Comment: I give up! If I don't know how Applicant and Spouse are related to each other and you can't explain clearly the results you want to achieve then I don't see how anyone can help you with this. -- Mr. Grumpy :-}

Comment: Applicant and Spouse are set previously based on the form input values. These values are used to check against the age. If the Spouse is a higher value than Applicant, and the Company = 27, then Spouse is set so the search on 27 should use the Spouse instead of Applicant for the returned results. All other records should be returned as normal with Applicant value. Does this help clarify?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to understand what you're looking for, but perhaps you want this?

```
([$ApplicantAge] BETWEEN Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age AND PlanDetail.company_id != 27) OR ([$PsSpouseAge] BETWEEN Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age AND PlanDetail.company_id = 27)
```

Comment: The problem is I am writing a conditional in CakePHP, and my output is such: WHERE ((19 BETWEEN `Age`.`Min_Age` AND `Age`.`Max_age`) AND (`Applicant`.`amount` IN ('as', '2')) AND (NOT (`PlanDetail`.`company_id` = 27)) AND (((21 BETWEEN `Age`.`Min_Age` AND `Age`.`Max_age`) AND (`PlanDetail`.`company_id` = 27))))

Comment: @OldWest I'm sorry, it's really not clear what you're trying to do.  I don't see much of a relation between this chunk of a query in your comment there, and the question you posted above.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question is just use UNION something like:

```
Select 'Applicant', Age 
Where $ApplicantAge BETWEEN Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age. NOT 'PlanDetail.company_id' <> '27'
Union
Select 'Spouse', Age
Where $PsSpouseAge BETWEEN Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age. WHERE 'PlanDetail.company_id' = '27'
```

However I think we are missing some important details on the relationship between applicant and Spouse.

Comment: Hi James, the relationship between the two is IF spouse is a higher value that applicant, then spouse is used but only for records ids that = 27. But all other records that hit should be pulled in as well.

Comment: Still missing the relationship between applicant and spouse, some table definitions would be nice! Also you say "higher value" but what is being compared "age" , "department" "Zip Code".